# AngularJS : update bindings ng-bind-html

Tags: angularjs

I've go a problem with binding. I use the "ng-bind-html" directive, because the details text of the object to display contains HTML code. Unfortunatly the text doesn't update when the object changes. 'title' and 'kurztext' change its values but 'langtext' (the html bound) not. Here's the code I use:

```
<div class="content scrollContainer" ng-model="selectedItem">
    <h2 class="header">{{selectedItem.titel}}</h2>
    <div class="kurztext" ng-show="selectedItem.kurztext">{{selectedItem.kurztext}}</div>
    <div class="langtext" ng-bind-html="selectedItem.langtext"></div>
</div>
```

In Javascript I just pick an object out of an array and assign it to $scope.selectedItem to change the displayed item. Here's my JS code (should not be relevant to the problem):

```
var items;

var app = angular.module("app", ["ngSanitize"]);

app.controller("MainCtrl", function ($scope, $sce){
    $scope.items = items;
    $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0];

    $scope.showItem = function(item){ // called on click on list item
        $scope.selectedItem = item;
    }

    $scope.openItemLink = function(id){
        for (var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
            if ($scope.items[i].uid==id){
                $scope.showItem($scope.items[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    $scope.getLink = function(id){
        var it = 0;
        for (var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++){
            if ($scope.items[i].uid==id){
                it = $scope.items[i];
                return it.titel;
            }
        }
        return "----";
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

you need to sanitize it, add angular-sanitize.js and in your module

```
var App = angular.module('process', ['ngSanitize']);
```

in your controller

```
App.controller(
    'Init',
    [
        '$scope', '$sce',
        function($scope, $sce)
```

and your code

```
$scope.details = $sce.parseAsHtml($scope.details);
```

i know that if i don't do that it doesnt work too,

according to the documentation

```
By default, the innerHTML-ed content will be sanitized using the $sanitize service.
 To utilize this functionality, ensure that $sanitize is available,
 for example, by         including ngSanitize in your module's dependencies (not in core  Angular.)
 You may also bypass sanitization for values you know are safe.
 To do so, bind to an explicitly trusted value via $sce.trustAsHtml.
 See the example under Strict Contextual Escaping (SCE).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I've already included $sanitize. I now put my JS code into the question above. The problem is that i don't manipulate the details text manually but use the object property directly. Should I instead $watch the object change and then create another variable containing the details text?

Comment: yes that can be a great solution, test and tell me if it works please